# Node: routing to a specific endpoint in a router file

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have an express app with a `users.js` route file:

```
const usersRoute = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users/', usersRoute);
```

However, I want to also access the "get specific user photo" route (`/users/:slug/photo`) from another root-level route (`/myrandomroute`). How can I do this from my `app.js`?

`app.use('/myrandomroute', usersRoute.get('/users/:id/picture')) // Doesn't work.`

Comment: What does "get specific user photo" mean in the context of a middleware handler?  What are you trying to do with that photo?  Also, `usersRoute.get('/users/:id/picture')` registers a route handler, it doesn't execute anything right now.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  What should the `app.use('/myrandomroute', ...)` middleware accomplish?

Comment: This is a contrived example. I want to forward all requests to `/myrandomroute` to a route that's already defined in the `usersRoute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just forward a request to another route, then you have at least two options.

First, you can make a named function out of the route you want to forward to, export that from that module and then in this route handler, when you determine within your route handler that you want to call that other route handler, you just call that other route handler function, passing it the appropriate `(req, res, next)` arguments from this handler.

Second, you can just use a `res.redirect()` to redirect the requester to the other route and let them come in freshly to the other route.

We could offer you a more specific coding solution if you showed us the actual code and described the precise situation you're trying to solve.

---

Then, some thoughts for future questions.  Contrived or made up examples without real code and real circumstances often leave us with lots of questions and they rob you of a chance for us to offer you the best solution to the actual problem which may be in a direction you haven't even thought to ask about.  Real code and real problems are always much better here than made up code examples.  For some reason, people think they should hide their real code and try to ask a generic question with pseudo-code and that's never a better option for you here.